# Start one activity from other onCreate method

Tags: java, android, android-activity, oncreate

#### Problem Description

I am writing Android application which contains two activities: `MainActivity` and `SplashActivity`. When `MainActivity`starts it takes some time to load UI and also it is doing some work in background. So in order not to show incomplete UI (white screen etc.) I decide start my `MainActivity` and right in its `onCreate()` method start `SplashActivity` and after some time close `SplashActivity` so I assume that at that point my `MainActivity` will be already loaded. So for this I tried the code below:

#### Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SetPassword.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);

        .........
    }
}
```

In a manifest file as a `LAUNCHER` activity is set `MainActivity`. This code follows as following:

1. `MainActivity` is shown.
2. When I close `MainActivity` `SplashActivity` comes to front.

**But I need following behavior**

1. `MainActivity` starts in 'background'
2. `SplashActivity` come to front and after some time close itself
3. `MainActivty' already loaded come to front.

Comment: You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `AsyncTask`. Start firs the `SplashActivity` and when all your necessary data is loaded, start the `MainActivity`. Try something like this:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Load your data here
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }

        };
        asyncTask.execute(null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not help as I have most problems with UI. UI is not shown correct white screen is shown for some time and after that the good screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could start a Dialog in your MainActivity. It will show up in front of the MainActivity and you can close it once the work is done background.

See here: [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your task could be solved by using fragments or views in one activity. 
In onCreate() method of activity you can show SplashFragment. When all background work is done you can replace it to MainFragment. The same thing could be achieved using different views (setting their visibility).

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        SplashFragment splashFragment = new SplashFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container,splashFragment).commit();
        }


    public void onLoad(){

        MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.fragment_container,mainFragment).commit();
        }
}
```

Any way. If you want to use activity, you need to use listener of you background job in SplashActivity. You should start SplashActivity using startActivityForResult(). When job is done you should finish your SplashActivity  and continue processing in onActivityResult() method in MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your splash screen first then navigate to MainActivity like this :

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    int timeout = 5000; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
        }, timeout);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

start your splash with 
NO_HISTORY Intent flag or define android:noHistory in manifest for ur splah activity